# How to receive xml responce without curl or code

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to learn SOAP and I was wondering if it was possible to view the responce of an xml message sent through a software? Preferably for Mac, without going through curl or code to view the response? If you know of a Windows app let me know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapUI allows you to craft SOAP requests from a template (derived from the WSDL) and see the responses. I think there is a Mac version of this as well as PC, as it's a Java app.

Edit: link to Mac download
http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Development/HTML/soapUI.shtml

Comment: thanks i've tried soapui and its very confusing to use. would you know of another one?

Comment: actually i've tried nusoap and i got it confused with this. let me take a look at it and i'll let you know what confuses me thanks

Comment: i read through the site and its confusing all it talks about it load testing and such. it doesnt show out to get a response xml file when sending an xml. it looks pretty useless

Comment: SoapUI is probably the best free tool to do what you want. I would recommend investing the time in learning how to use it.

Comment: i'm trying dave to read the entire site and make sense out of it. what really sucks is that all tutorials that exist on soap is not written for beginners to make sense out of it. they all contain complex xml syntax that doesnt make any sense to me. hopefully this software will shine some light.

Comment: Ok, would it be worth going back a step and reading up on SOAP messages and how they are used first?